# running jar with multiple arguments from batch file

Tags: java, batch-file, jar

The following is a snippet from a batch file where I try to run `myProgram.jar`

```
set /p _count="enter count: "
set /p _toc="enter TOC"

choice /N /C:TO /M "Select Type(T/O): "
if errorlevel ==1 set _type=T
if errorlevel ==2 set _type=O

choice /N /C:SF /M "Select status(S/F): "
if errorlevel ==1 set _status=T
if errorlevel ==2 set _status=O

java -jar dir/myProgram.jar %_count% %_type% %_status% %_toc%
```

The batch file executes the `java -jar` command with four arguments namely `_count`, `_type`, `_status` and `_toc`.

I only get the values of `_count` and `_toc` in java.

The problem is the remaining two parameters are getting passed as `null` values and as a result I am facing `NullPointerException` everytime I run the program.

Comment: I tried your code and it works. It seems that the problem doesn't lay on the batch file.

Comment: The problem is for String[] args in main(), only args[0] and args[3] take the values of _count and _toc. I am still unable to figure out why args[1] and args[2] contain null values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### tl;dr

Your error can't be reproduced and I'm quite sure it leads to a simple typographical error or in your Java App, which you didn't show to us.

---

I did the following to reproduce your behavior:

### 1. Create a simple Java App, writing `args` to the console:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Arrays.stream(args).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

### 2. Compile it using `jdk1.8.0_91` on Windows 10.

```
javac .\App.java
jar cvfe App.jar App *.class
```

### 3. Execute test.bat with your above code: (Just for the case you edit your question)

```
set /p _count="enter count: "
set /p _toc="enter TOC"

choice /N /C:TO /M "Select Type(T/O): "
if errorlevel ==1 set _type=T
if errorlevel ==2 set _type=O

choice /N /C:SF /M "Select status(S/F): "
if errorlevel ==1 set _status=T
if errorlevel ==2 set _status=O

java -jar App.jar %_count% %_type% %_status% %_toc%
```

With the inputs: `5, 6, T, F` it gave the following output:

> 5
>     T
>     O
>     6

That means - IMHO - your error lays in your java code obtaining `args`, the `NullPointerException` is thrown by `System.Console()` and not `args[n]`, or your posted batch code isn't exactly how it is executed on your computer.

To sum it up: If your batch calls the command line with 4 parameters (like your example code does), `args` has 4 parameters.

Comment: The batch file passes all four parameters to java.

_args_ also receives four parameters.

The problem is only _args[1]_ and _args[2]_ take null values whereas _args[0]_ and _args[3]_ take the respective numeric values passed in the .bat file

I have tried passing literals (A,B,C, etc) in place of _%_type%_ and _%_status%_. It works! But passing the variables don't.

Comment: Again: **It works!** without any failure. If you are going through the steps I provided, the output is exactly as I said. Edit your question and add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That means, add your Java code exactly like you've written it so that one can reproduce your error. As of now, it can't be reproduced and seems off topic to me.

Comment: Unless java is radically different from my expectation, if arg[3] has content, surely arg[2] and arg[1] couldn't be null, you would have two arguments, arg[0] and arg[1]. Perhaps you should post the appropriate section of `myProgram.jar` for verification.

Comment: Word! ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: The problem indeed was in the preceding batch code.

Comment: @AbhishekRoy And what exactly was the problem?

Comment: Its embarrassing. Actually, before the command _java -jar_ there are some if statements to check the value of __toc_ based on which the values of __type_ and __status_ would be populated accordingly. I was populating the variable inside **_if_** locally. I felt like shooting myself after finally discovering the mistake. Thanks for you help though.

Answer (score 0):

From `CHOICE/?`:

```
When you use ERRORLEVEL parameters in a batch program, list them in decreasing order.
```

That means you use the following syntax:

```
If ErrorLevel 2 Set "_type=O"
If ErrorLevel 1 Set "_type=T"
```

An often used alternative, if you prefer it, is to use `%ERRORLEVEL%` instead:

```
If "%ErrorLevel%"=="1" Set "_status=T"
If "%ErrorLevel%"=="2" Set "_status=O"
```

Comment: I tried you solution but it didn't help. The problem is for String[] args in main(), only args[0] and args[3] take the values of _count and _toc. args[1] and args[2] contain null values.

Comment: If you don't expand your code section to include enough of the code above that which we can currently see then we cannot help you further. The code I've provided is robust and correct, your error must lie in something you haven't yet revealed. _If the simple structure in your question was wrong in your script, there's a likelihood that there are others above it_.

Comment: Thanks for the update, please remember nonetheless to change your fixed code to match the syntax and layout exactly as in one of the two examples above.